# Why 3 outputs for 2 comparisons in python?

Tags: python, comparison

I am trying following code:

```
In [16]: a,b = 1,2
```

Above allocates 1 to a and 2 to b as expected and there is no error message:

```
In [18]: a
Out[18]: 1

In [19]: b
Out[19]: 2
```

But if I try to compare them together:

```
In [17]: a,b == 1,2
Out[17]: (1, False, 2)
```

I get 3 outputs. Where is the problem or what do these 3 outputs mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no problem here. It is evaluated like this

```
(a, (b == 1), 2)
```

A tuple of three values.

In Python the surrounding parentheses are not necessary to create a tuple if it has more than one elements. So as per Python grammar, this is treated as a tuple. This is documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#expression-lists),

> Except when part of a list or set display, an expression list containing at least one comma yields a tuple. The length of the tuple is the number of expressions in the list. The expressions are evaluated from left to right.

...

> The trailing comma is required only to create a single tuple (a.k.a. a singleton); it is optional in all other cases. A single expression without a trailing comma doesn’t create a tuple, but rather yields the value of that expression. (To create an empty tuple, use an empty pair of parentheses: ().)

---

To achieve what you want, you need to do it like this

```
(a, b) == (1, 2)
```

Comment: So how can I evaluate both of them together and get 1 or 2 comparison outputs?

Comment: Can I get 2 comparison outputs while using one `==` comparison operator?

Comment: Nope. That is not possible.

Comment: `list(map(lambda x,y: x==y, [a,b],[1,2]))` ?

Comment: It is not a valid expression. Even if you did `list(map(lambda x,y: x==y, [[a,b],[1,2]]))`, the comparison operator is executed for each inner item in the list.

Comment: Why are you enclosing both lists in one list. My code `list(map(lambda x,y: x==y, [a,b],[1,2]))` works OK on my system.

Comment: Ah, my bad... It works. My point is still valid. This is similar to doing the comparison in a loop.

Comment: Why "`a,b = 1,2`" is not "`a , (b = 1) , 2`" ?

Comment: That is explained [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#evaluation-order). When `=` is used, the expression becomes L.H.S and R.H.S. Here LHS is a tuple and RHS is a tuple. The values are assigned with one to one correspondence.

Answer (score 1):

```
a,b = 1,2
```

This is multiple assignment where the variables a and b are simultaneously given the values 1 and 2. The right-hand side expressions are evaluated from the left to the right first.

```
  a,b==1,2
```

Here only the b==1 is taken. That is why the result is 1,True,2

Answer (score 1):

The `dis` module in the python helps you to see whats going under the hood

```
>>> from dis import dis

>>> def bo(a=2,b=3):
...     print a,b==2,3
... 
>>> dis(bo)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
              3 PRINT_ITEM          
              4 LOAD_FAST                1 (b)
              7 LOAD_CONST               1 (2)
             10 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             13 PRINT_ITEM          
             14 LOAD_CONST               2 (3)
             17 PRINT_ITEM          
             18 PRINT_NEWLINE       
             19 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             22 RETURN_VALUE        
>>> bo()
2 False 3
>>> def bo(a=2,b=3):
...     print a,b==3,2
... 
>>> bo()
2 True 2
```

> if we use `a,b==3,2` when `a=2` and `b=3` the tuple `s middle element will
>   have True value

First `a` and `b` are pushed onto the stack the popped of the stack and compared with corresponding values and then made into a tuple .

So in effect the comparison is done in the reverse order

So reversing the order of elements provides us a correct value in the resulting tuple

**In short**

```
def bo(a=1,b=2,c=3,d=4):
    print a,b,c,d==4,3,2,1
bo()
```

will print

```
1 2 3 True 3 2 1
```

So we can access the tuples middle element for correct value